# Firestore Options - setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled() is deprecated

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am using the following code in my backend to initialize Firestore as per the documentation:

```
// Use the application default credentials
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(credentials)
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

But when I write to Firestore from my backend I get this warning:

> The behavior for java.util.Date objects stored in Firestore is going
>   to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK. (FirestoreImpl.java:90) To hide this
>   warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the
>   following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore
>   methods:
>
> ```
> FirestoreOptions options =   
> FirestoreOptions.newBuilder().setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true).build();
> Firestore firestore = options.getService();
> ```
>
> With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read
>   back as com.google.cloud.Timestamp objects instead of as system
>   java.util.Date objects. So you will also need to update code expecting
>   a java.util.Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:
>
> ```
> // Old: java.util.Date date = (java.util.Date)
> snapshot.get("created_at"); 
> // New: Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp)
> snapshot.get("created_at"); java.util.Date date = timestamp.toDate();
> ```
>
> Please audit all existing usages of java.util.Date when you enable the
>   new behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the
>   new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

This warning led me to believe that since I am using Firestore I should be using `FirestoreOptions` to initiate the Admin SDK. Yet, when I tried to initialize the Admin SDK using `FirestoreOptions`, `setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled()` is marked as deprecated.

I am being told I need to use `FirebaseOptions` however.

Where to go from here?

Comment: What version of the Admin SDK are you using?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 6.10.0

Comment: Hmm... in that case I have no idea. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen maybe a bug can be filed at google?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have two different versions of google-cloud-firestore in your classpath. The warning you're seeing was removed at the same time the `setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled()` method was deprecated: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/pull/4353

Check you classpath. You probably have both 0.x and 1.x versions of Firestore in there.

Comment: I don't think so. The only imports I have are: `import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;` and the only dependency is `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.10.0`

Comment: Can you verify which version of `google-cloud-firestore` is in your classpath?

Comment: Firestore 1.x.x does not log the above warning. That code was removed completely at the 1.0.0 release. If you're still seeing the warning, then your runtime is somehow picking up an older (0.x.x) version of the Firestore library.

Comment: No idea then. Not sure what to do. Thanks for the help though.